# Unable to figure out how to add data to existing data lake file

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using the Azure SDK for .NET to manipulate files on the data lake (Gen2).
Within an Azure Function, I would like to add some data to a csv file stored on the data lake.

I came up with this method, should work according to the documentation (or I did not fully understand it).

Problem is that the data is not 'flushed' to the file. It remains the original content.
Can't figure out what's going on here i'm afraid :-(

Any tips ?

Regards,
Sven Peeters

PS : I must add data incrementally, otherwise the memory consumption can become an issue here.

```
public void AddFileContents(string fullPath, string content, string leaseId = null)
    {
        DataLakeFileClient dataLakeFileClient = GetFileSystemClient().GetFileClient(fullPath);
        dataLakeFileClient.CreateIfNotExists();

        long currentLength = dataLakeFileClient.GetProperties().Value.ContentLength;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        long fileSize = mStream.Length;

        dataLakeFileClient.Append(mStream, currentLength, leaseId: leaseId);
        dataLakeFileClient.Flush(position: currentLength, close: true, conditions: new DataLakeRequestConditions() { LeaseId = leaseId });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakefileclient.flush?view=azure-dotnet#parameters), you should change `position: currentLength` to `position: currentLength + fileSize` in `Flush` method. The position parameter should equal to the length of file after you appended.

> To flush, the previously uploaded data must be contiguous, the
> position parameter must be specified and equal to the length of the
> file after all data has been written, and there must not be a request
> entity body included with the request.

Code:

```
public static void AddFileContents(string fullPath, string content, string leaseId = null)
{
    DataLakeFileClient dataLakeFileClient = GetFileSystemClient().GetFileClient(fullPath);
    dataLakeFileClient.CreateIfNotExists();

    long currentLength = dataLakeFileClient.GetProperties().Value.ContentLength;

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    long fileSize = mStream.Length;

    dataLakeFileClient.Append(mStream, currentLength, leaseId: leaseId);
    dataLakeFileClient.Flush(position: currentLength + fileSize, close: true, conditions: new DataLakeRequestConditions() { LeaseId = leaseId });
}
```

Comment: I figured it out yesterday too, was planning to update my post today.

Nevertheless , Thank you very much for your clear solution